# FPGA for PHP script dongle

Tags: php

I'm considering to deploy my PHP project to my clients. As of now I'm selling my software as a SaaS but this is becoming a not viable method anymore for my infrastructure.

I'm aware that there is no way on this planet to prevent a software from being cracked/copied. Even hardware dongles can be bypassed.

Despite what software companies claim, all software that encrypt PHP files for licensing purposes produce decryptable PHP sources. I mean, ALL, as july 2020. Even PHP comments are recoverable from encrypted PHP files.

There is no way to secure a PHP file if the decrypt key resides on the same machine that decrypts said file. PHP script encrypters are placebo.

Please don't state that I should accept to be cracked and that I should make a living from support tickets because I will ignore such answers.

My hardcore idea comes from ATMs where the software is cryptographically signed and only secure software can be executed by the ATM CPU.

What if I delivered a FPGA device to my clients that implements a simple AES decrypter?

What if I managed to code a PHP extension that feeds the FPGA with the encrypted PHP scripts and waits in return the decrypted PHP scripts before running them?

This way the AES key would be burned onto the FPGA chip and there would be no way to recover it by ordinary hackers.

Another solution would be to deliver a mini x86 or ARM PC to my clients that doesn't have microSD slots, USB ports, jtag pins, only internal storage. I'd load linux into it along with my PHP software and the only security measure would be the root password, but I don't know if such PC exists.

Since there are professional polemical people that always ask, where is the question? I answer, the question is right there. If you can't find it don't answer.

All suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment of an ARM processor would serve your purpose with lesser efforts.

Getting any good ARM development board with features such as:

- Ethernet port
- Linux installation option

Would do the job real quick.

Core code made as part of internal flash memory would make it secure.

Comment: But you could boot said ARM board with U-BOOT from an external SD or USB to gain access to the internal flash memory, like you would do with a PC with a live CD, right?